# WPF frontend to CRM

Tags: wpf, dynamics-crm

Slide 19 of [this](http://www.slideshare.net/topline/top-line-strategies-ms-xrm) presentation, shows a WPF/Silverlight frontend to a CRM application.

What I am wondering is: Is there some standard functionality in CRM that generates these screens. Or are they just a normal WPF app that calls CRM via web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a normal WPF/silverlight app that calls CRM via web services. There is no standard functionality to generate such forms from CRM. All CRM user interfaces (web, mobile, outlook, ...) are implemented on top of the same web service(s).

You may however open web forms directly if you have the GUID of the element. (ie. open an account web form passing the GUID as a URL argument)

**Edit:** 
Just got an idea on how to solve this. Forms in CRM can be exported to XML. This XML should be possible to transform into XAML (maybe using XSLT?). I'm not saying its easy but it should be doable.